# Loop until the value is null

Tags: php, loops

i need to loop the process of deleting if there is an id in the database that the user input. can someone help me about this?

```
 //my php code 
 $ppnum=$_POST['pnum'];

while ($ppnum !== null)) {
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

 mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM tbldd WHERE pnum ='$ppnum'");

mysqli_close($con);}
```

Comment: what is it currently doing now? try to describe your problem in more detail.  from the looks of this, that loop will never terminate if entered in to because you're never updating the value of `$ppnum`

Comment: What is inside `$_POST['pnum']`?

Comment: You're not using `while` correctly here, it should be `if(isset($_POST['pnum']))` and then you should be using `try{ //connection }catch(Exception $e){}`

Comment: [Bobby Tables would love your code](http://xkcd.com/327).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes This is still funny, even if not a new one ;-)

Comment: the value of $_POST['BMHC-2014-0001']

Comment: the $_POST['pnum'] will it contain one id or multiple ids ?

Comment: the only deleting here is the last record

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this? This assume $_POST['pnum'] is comma separated list of ids.

```
$ppnum=$_POST['pnum'];

$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM tbldd WHERE pnum in ($ppnum)");

mysqli_close($con);
```

but you MUST check $_POST['pnum'] against sql injection attack.

Comment: i need to delete all the records that having that pnum using a loop because there will be a saving too after the deleting process

Comment: @Lia Chi, This will delete all record contain in the $_POST['pnum']. ie if $_POST['pnum'] = '1,3,8,12' then this query will delete records with pnum 1,3,8 and 12. I am not understand second part of your comment :(